# Not Able To See Error Message Even tThe Column Name Is Invalid in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

My Problem is , i was unable to see `Error Message` (Red Underline) in MS SQL  although  the column name is invalid ( Column name is not present ) ... i was Struggling when i was Executing stored procedures ill get bundle of error in my console.

[image]

Help Me...
Thank's In Advance.

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 [BU_Region_ID]
      ,[Business_Unit_ID]
      ,[Region_ID]
      ,[CRTS]
      ,[CRUSER]
      ,[UPTS]
      ,[UPUSER]
      ,[Is_Serving_Region]
      ,[Is_Active]
      ,sometext
  FROM [My_Hosur].[dbo].[tbl_ENT_BU_Regions]
```

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL + Shift + R
Its refresh an intellisense

Comment: I have Done this @Munavvar but still it is not showing as an error.

Comment: Just try another thing, Please select your Database as default database for this query window.
Currently master is selected.

Just write a statement on above your query.

use [My_Hosur]
GO

Comment: And also you can check that, Is IntelliSense enabled or not? You can check it from menu item Query --> IntellisenseEnable